# Basic spring boot app not working, showing: Failed to refresh live data from process xxxx

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am beginner for spring boot. I initialized a new project and tried to run it but it does not work successfully. WHen I run this as spring boot application, it starts execution. In bottom compiler/status bar, it shows processing and retrying. it goes upto 10 times and throw the following error:

[Failed to refresh live data from process xxxx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7VPO.jpg)

[More detail here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWM0m.png)

**TanmayTestApplication.java**

```
package com.example.tanmay_test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TanmayTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TanmayTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**DemoControler.java**

```
package com.example.cntr;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class DemoControler {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/index")
    public String index() {
        return "By Tanmay!";
    }   
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>tanmay_test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tanmay_test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you changed your pom, try maven>Update Project. Else do a run as > maven clean and run as > maven install and then try running it again. Not to mention, check your internet connection too.

Comment: @AjayKumar When I run as > maven clean and run as > maven install, it shows a warning: `[WARNING] The requested profile "pom.xml" could not be activated because it does not exist.` but pom.xml exists as you can see in the question above.

Comment: Right click on project. Properties > Click Maven node. Delete pom.xml from Active Maven Profiles. Apply and Close. You should be good to go.

Comment: Hey guys! I got here with the same issue, did the same as said above, but still when running my application I still get the same message. Seems that the application, as it is right now, is not having any failures, but I'm afraid it will show failures in the future when it gets bigger, so I'm looking for a solution. Any other ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Add this line in your file **application.properties** (src/main/resources):

**spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true**

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in STS, and tried different things to resolve it. The following dependency for spring actuator makes that problem disappear, but however the main point of spring actuator provides more features than this. To learn more, click https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

The dependency should be added to your pom.xml file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem but managed to solve it.
The controller class has to be in the "child package" relative to the `TestApplication` class.

In your case, your `TanmayTestApplication` class is in the package `com.example.tanmay_test`. Therefore, your `DemoControler` class must be inside the package `com.example.tanmay_test.xxx`.

**Note that xxx can be anything but extends from package `com.example.tanmay_test`. For example, package `com.example.tanmay_test.web`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried your solution, but with no luck. It still throw the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Live data is collected with the help of Spring Actuator.

You need to include the following dependency in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

See https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Live-Application-Information#application-requirements-for-spring-boot-projects for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue after adding Spring Actuator dependency, it resolved.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

after adding this in POM.xml, do maven build and run again.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply saying that you didn't enable [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This is non other then the **Data Source** error
To resolves this I disabled the **auto-configuration** of the DataSource. And, this will not affect auto-configuring any other beans.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using VS Code and the thing that worked for me was adding a dev tool dependency.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
          </dependency>
```

Also, add `spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=true` in application.properties file so that server knows that it has to reload every time a change is made.
[Thanks for this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60678196/18301333)