# Spring boot first start localhost don't work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am beginner for spring boot. I initialized a new project and tried to run it but it does not work successfully. WHen I run this as spring boot application, it starts execution. In bottom compiler/status bar, it shows processing and retrying. And throw the following error:

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/lsperror-png

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/whatsapp_image_2020-03-20_at_18-51-26-jpeg

When I try to access localhost:8080 don't work. Sorry my english.

Tys for help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question as of right now can not be answered. Please show us, what you have tried so far. Please add the code to your question using proper formatting. Please avoid linking to off site ressources, as these might change in the future.
Please take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details on how to ask good questions. Also, check out the beginner tour, it's quite nice and you get an achievement: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010007/basic-spring-boot-app-not-working-showing-failed-to-refresh-live-data-from-pro) will help